# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to model.User

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security in my application. I need loggedIn user details in the controllers of my application.

For that I am using this code

```
User loggedInUser = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

But on running this code I get a classcastexception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to model.User
```

To fix this I referred to this [article](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/-Spring-Security-Customizing-Your-User-and-Authorization-in)

Initially I used a CustomUserServiceDetails class

```
@Service("myUserDetailService")
@Transactional
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        // returns the get(0) of the user list obtained from the db
        User domainUser = userDAO.getUser(name);
        logger.debug("User fetched from database in loadUserByUsername method " + domainUser);

        Set<Role> roles = domainUser.getRole();
        logger.debug("role of the user" + roles);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(Role role: roles){
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
            logger.debug("role" + role + " role.getRole()" + (role.getRole()));
        }

        boolean credentialNonExpired = true;

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(domainUser.getProfileName(), domainUser.getPassword(), domainUser.isAccountEnabled(),
                domainUser.isAccountNonExpired(), credentialNonExpired, domainUser.isAccountNonLocked(),authorities);

    }

}
```

But after referring to the article I removed the setting of GrantedAuthorities from here and moved it to my User class. Implemented spring-security UserDetails class in my User class

Now I have an extra property in my User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
```

with a setMethod

```
public void setAuthorities(Set<Role> roles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(Role role: roles){
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));}
    }
```

A. I am not sure how to map this property to the database. The existing User table schema doesn't contain a GrantedAuthority column besides It's not even a primitive type. I am using Hibernate for object mapping. Can anyone advice me the correct approach to obtain the user class info in the controllers?

B. I also considered the approach of extending the spring's User class and overloading the constructor of my User class. But then every time I initialize my User anywhere in the code I have to provide all the constructors parameters which is not good at all.

Comment: Why... Just let your `Role` class implement `GrantedAuthority`....

Comment: Do you still have the ClassCastException ? In my application, MyUserDetails extends MyUser (the user in the database) and implements UserDetails (spring security). This way I can have all the informations I need about the logged in user.

Comment: Have you created an overloaded constructor in MyUserDetails? As I understand by your statement Bilal that I need to create a separate MyUserDetails class then extend my model User & implement UserDetails?

Comment: Yes I overloaded the constructor. You don't "need" to do that, your code should work.

Comment: I am having similar issues as you did. If it's okay with you, can you share a bare bones snipped of your project resolving the issue under discussion in this thread?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed the issue

**Solution**

Created a CustomUserDetail class which implements Spring's UserDetails interface. Injected my model User class in it.

```
public class CustomUserDetail implements UserDetails{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private User user;

    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities=null;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities)
    {
        this.authorities=authorities;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getProfileName();
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return user.isAccountNonExpired();
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return user.isAccountNonLocked();
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return user.isCredentialsNonExpired();
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.isAccountEnabled();
    }

}
```

CustomUserServiceDetails

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public CustomUserDetail loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        // returns the get(0) of the user list obtained from the db
        User domainUser = userDAO.getUser(name);


        Set<Role> roles = domainUser.getRole();
        logger.debug("role of the user" + roles);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(Role role: roles){
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
            logger.debug("role" + role + " role.getRole()" + (role.getRole()));
        }

        CustomUserDetail customUserDetail=new CustomUserDetail();
        customUserDetail.setUser(domainUser);
        customUserDetail.setAuthorities(authorities);

        return customUserDetail;

    }

}
```

In my controller method

```
CustomUserDetail myUserDetails = (CustomUserDetail) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        Integer userId=myUserDetails.getUser().getUserId(); //Fetch the custom property in User class
```

Comment: You can use @AuthenticationPrincipal to get your CustomUserDetails instead of getting it from the Context Holder.

Comment: My Spring security version is less than 3.2, I believe the annotation is unavailable in earlier versions of Spring security.

Comment: did you get userId from this?

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using

```
User loggedInUser = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

try this

```
Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String username = loggedInUser.getName();
```

References:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-security/

Answer (score 2):

The method **.getPrincipal()** returns the object created and returned it in the method loadUserByUsername.

If you want an User you must return in the method loadUserByUsername an User, not an org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User