# Spring Security - AuthenticationSuccessHandler ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot + Spring Security and trying to implement an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` so that the app can save a last login timestamp to the database for the user.

Below is my attempt at the code. The issue is I'm getting a class cast exception because it does not like my cast to `User` from `authentication`.

**Error**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.example.model.User
```

**Code**

```
@Component
public class SecurityHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    // Exception throw here during cast
    User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
    user.setLastLogin(new Date());
    userService.saveUser(user);

    handle(request, response, authentication);
  }

  protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    String targetUrl = "/dashboard";
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to model.User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276482/java-lang-classcastexception-org-springframework-security-core-userdetails-user)